# Send Notification to an AD Security Group using Nintex Workflow 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

We use SP 2010 + Nintex Workflow Enterprise 2010.
Question: I am using Send Notification action to send an email to the AD group.

The email is sent to individual users however the group members do not receive an email.

Is there a configuration setting that I might be missing?

Thanks